# Why I cant get index from map to function?

Tags: reactjs

Click handler:

```
 const deleteHandler = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>, i: number) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        dispatch(deleteOffer(i)) //undefined
    }
```

Usage into React Component

```
  {offers.map((o, i) => (
                <div key={i} className={classes['OffersList__item']}>
                    <UIButton type={'primary'} onClick={(e:React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>, i: number) => deleteHandler(e, i)}>
                        <FaTrash/>
                    </UIButton>
                </div>
            ))}
```

Why am I getting 'undefined' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
onClick={(e:React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>, i: number) => deleteHandler(e, i)}
```

Do

```
onClick={(e:React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => deleteHandler(e, i)}
```

`i` doesn't exist in onClick mouse event, and this is also overriding your original index. That is also why typescript asked you to type the `i`'s type otherwise `i` would have been inferred already.